# How to find out if pipe is broken?

Tags: shell-script, scripting, pipe, posix, printf

I have a POSIX shell script which has its standard output `1` redirected to a pipe. At some point of the script execution, the pipe will break and I'd like to find out (in my shell script) when that happens.

So I tried this:

```bash
(
  trap "" PIPE  # prevent shell from terminating due to SIGPIPE
  while :; do
    echo trying to write to stdout >&2
    echo writing something to stdout || break
    echo successfully written to stdout >&2
    sleep 1
  done
  echo continuing here after loop >&2
) | sleep 3
```

Which prints:

```
trying to write to stdout
successfully written to stdout
trying to write to stdout
successfully written to stdout
trying to write to stdout
successfully written to stdout
trying to write to stdout
sh: 5: echo: echo: I/O error
continuing here after loop
```

In this example, we're using `sleep` as a replacement for the program that my script writes its stdout to. After 3 seconds, `sleep` terminates and the pipe breaks.

We're only piping stdout to `sleep`, so we can still use stderr for a few debugging messages in between.

Writing to a broken pipe leads to SIGPIPE whose default action is termination of the program, according to [POSIX `signal.h`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/signal.h.html). That's why we have to `trap` the signal and ignore it.

After `sleep` terminates, the pipe breaks, subsequent `echo writing something to stdout` leads to SIGPIPE, which gets trapped (ignored), `echo` fails and `|| break` exits the loop. The script continues without any problems.

So my example above works perfectly fine. The obvious major downside is, that I'm spamming the pipe with lots of "writing something to stdout" just to find out if the pipe is still working. If I replace `echo writing something to stdout` with `printf ""` to "write" to the pipe, no SIGPIPE will be raised and the loop just continues, even though the pipe is long broken already.

What could I do instead?

Comment: Catch the `PIPE` signal with a `trap`?

Comment: @Kusalananda Thank you! :) I have edited the question to include a `trap` for SIGPIPE. As far as I can tell, this doesn't help with the problem because I still have to write to the broken pipe first and only then I get SIGPIPE.

Answer (score 2):

> At some point of the script execution, the pipe will break and I'd like to find out when that happens.

You can only tell that if you try to write to the pipe.

Based on the Linux man pages, it looks to me like any `write()` call to the write-end of a pipe with no reader should give the signal/error, even if writing zero bytes. But the shells I tried skip the whole system call if there's nothing to print, so that doesn't help.

If you do write non-zero amounts of data, you may find the script blocked on the write at some point, that is if the readers neglect to do their job and the pipe buffer gets full.

Then again, you said in a comment:

> I think I basically want to use select/poll from the shell script.

... and that's a situation where you really should switch from the shell to a proper programming language. Or just switch to Zsh, it has the `zselect` module that works as a frontend to `select()`: https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Zsh-Modules.html#The-zsh_002fzselect-Module

Not that I'm sure `select()` will help you find when the read end of the pipe is closed.

Comment: POSIX leaves it unspecified what  `write(1, "",  0)` does on a pipe and on Linux, I find it doesn't do anything even on a broken pipe.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas, yeh, the [man page I was reading](https://manpages.debian.org/bullseye/manpages/pipe.7.en.html) says "If all file descriptors referring to the read end of a pipe have been closed, then a write(2) will cause a SIGPIPE signal to be generated for the calling process." though I'm not surprised a zero-byte write would be different. But as mentioned, it doesn't matter here.

Answer (score 2):

On Linux and FreeBSD at least, using `poll()` with a `POLLERR` mask works at detecting  broken pipes.

There's no CLI interface to `poll()` in the POSIX toolchest but you could use `perl` which is more often available than not (contrary to many POSIX utilities such as `pax`, `bc` or `m4` for that matters):

```
perl -MIO::Poll -e '$p=IO::Poll->new; $p->mask(STDOUT,POLLERR); $p->poll'
```

Would return when the pipe on stdout becomes broken.

For your use case of terminating a remote command when the ssh client is terminated:

```bash
ssh host '
  exec perl -MIO::Poll -we '\''
    $SIG{CHLD} = sub{wait; exit($? & 127 ? 128|($?&127) : $?>>8)};
    exec "sleep 3600 # example" unless fork;
    $p = IO::Poll->new;
    $p->mask(STDOUT, POLLERR);
    $p->poll;
    kill "HUP", 0'\'
```

Note that on Linux, a pipe can be unbroken by someone opening `/proc/$pid/fd/$fd` in read or read+write mode where `$fd` is a fd of process `$pid` opened in write mode to the pipe.

```
$ exec 3> >(:)
$ perl -MIO::Poll -e '$p=IO::Poll->new; $p->mask(STDOUT,POLLERR); $p->poll'  >&3 && echo broken
broken
$ exec 4< /dev/fd/3
$ echo unbroken >&3
$ cat <&4
unbroken
```

It seems to me that  rather to poll for that condition, you should instead live with it and handle the condition.

With shells where `printf` is builtin:

```
(
  trap 'echo>&2 Pipe is broken' PIPE
  while printf 'Whatever\n'; do
    sleep 1
  done
) | sleep 5
```

Would handle the SIGPIPE. If `printf` is not builtin, then it's the process executing it that will die of a SIGPIPE. Which you  can check based on the exit status with `[ "$(kill -l "$?") = PIPE ]`.

If you ignore SIGPIPE, such as with `trap '' PIPE` then processes (including children) don't get a SIGPIPE when they write to a broken pipe but their `write()` still fails with `EPIPE` (that error often handled by exiting the process).

### edit

As noted by @TheDiveO [this similar question](/q/764906), Linux' `select()` (and that's also the case with FreeBSD's) will return an fd opened even in write-only mode to a pipe when that pipe is broken if it's in the list of watched fds for *reading*.

```
$ zmodload zsh/zselect
$ (zselect -r 1; echo>&2 done) | sleep 1
done
```

So if sshing to a system where the login shell is zsh, you can just do:

```
ssh host '
  zmodload zsh/zselect
  cmd 3> >(zselect -r 0 -r 1; kill -s HUP 0)'
```

Where `zselect` returns if it sees EOF on either its stdin (a pipe to the fd 3 of cmd) to detect cmd terminating or its stdout to detect the broken pipe. Then it kills it whole process group (0), including `cmd` if still running, the subshell running for the process substitution and the shell.

Answer (score 1):

`tail` in your OS may or may not be able to tell when its stdout is a broken pipe even without writing to it. See [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1405010/432690) to [*Why isn't `tail -f … | grep -q …` quitting when it finds a match?*](https://superuser.com/q/1404982/432690)

Modern `tail` from GNU Coreutils is able to tell.

*If* your `tail` is that smart and *if* you're sure the stdout is a pipe then run `tail -f /dev/null` in your script. The command will exit immediately after the pipe breaks.

Proof of concept (it requires "smart" `tail`, e.g. from GNU Coreutils):

```bash
sh -c 'tail -f /dev/null; echo >&2 "Pipe broken!"' | sleep 5
#      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^    this is our script
#                                                  ^ this pipe will break after 5 seconds
```

Notes:

- `tail -f /dev/null` prints nothing.
- If stdout was e.g. a regular file then `tail -f /dev/null` would *not* exit by itself, ever.
- I tested with `tail` from GNU Coreutils 8.32 in Kubuntu 22.10.
- For comparison: `busybox tail -f /dev/null` is not "smart", it just sits there even after the pipe breaks.

Comment: "readable event on STDOUT is equivalent to POLLERR, and implies an error condition on output like broken pipe." -- ehh, I guess that's one way to implement it...

Comment: Interesting, thank you! However, GNU coreutils `tail` probably won't be available. However... hmm... could I still use this somehow? Doing the same as `tail` does? Trying to read from stdout?  https://github.com/coreutils/coreutils/blob/65bb2765646df18488b266e6c1851593d3f9c966/src/tail.c#L382

Comment: @finefoot I'm not a programmer and at this moment I cannot help you further.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski No worries :) My comment wasn't even directed at you specifically. Again, thank you very much for your answer.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think that pipe will break. When you use the OR operator (||) in bash, it almost always disregards it, as it is generally for conditionals (if statements).

If this program is just a test for another program, I'd recommend using a `for` loop.

```
char='1 2 3 4 5' # Change this to whatever you want
for i in $char; do
  printf "Something"
done
```

You can also do a range:

```
for i in {1..[your number]}; do
  printf "Something"
done
```

Hope that helps. Good luck!

Comment: What do you mean "it almost always disregards it"? In my experience `||` works just fine in what it does, namely running the second command only if the first failed. I'm also not sure what all this has to do with pipes?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @ilkkachu, that's what I meant buddy. Why would printf fail? The poster used fine syntax, so it wouldn't break.

Comment: @theguy123, see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4584904/what-causes-the-broken-pipe-error https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Broken_pipe It has nothing to do with anything in `printf` failing per se, but with there being nothing to write _to_. Nothing here seems to address that. I'm also not sure why you'd say the shell "disregards" the `||` operator, if you know it works fine in what it does?

Comment: @ilkkachu, sorry. The language in my post wasn’t the clearest it could be. By “disregards”, I meant that unless the command fails in some way, the loop wouldn’t break.